# OpenVPN Server - CPU is pegged out

Tags: openvpn

I am configuring OpenVPN to act as a SSL tunnel for a remote location. I have OpenVPN1 at our current location acting as a server then OpenVPN2 at the other location that is acting as a client but is also acting as a DHCP server to machines behind it so they are basically connected to the local LAN. Everything is set up fine and I can talk from location A to location B with no problems like everyone is local. I am however having some performance issues. OpenVPN1 CPU is pegged to 100% the entire time I am copying or doing any type of activity through the tunnel. I expect some CPU usage going up but nothing like this. It's really killing my performance. OpenVPN1 is running in ESX right now with 2 gig RAM and 4 procs with unlimited bursting capacity. I am using AES-192 encryption with a 1024 key. Any idea how I can get my CPU down on OpenVPN1 and my download/upload speeds higher between the tunnel? Thanks.

edit: Turning down the logging helped boost the throughput a little bit, but I am still fairly shy of where I believe I should be. Also I am still maxed out on the CPU. Does anyone have any ideas? I am really stuck on this.

Comment: Can you post the configuration files (excluding the PSK and any DNS/IP addresses of course)

Answer (score 1):

what's the speed of internet connection between both ends? openvpn on modern hardware can easily handle 100Mbit/s or more of traffic.

do you run tun or tap mode? tap tun/routed should give you better performance.

Comment: We have a gig connection between all of the links and we are using tun interfaces. I am only getting around a 5 meg download speed from a point A file server to a point B laptop.

Comment: @than there is something seriously wrong. check connectivity between vpn endpoints with iperf - first over the tunnel, than directly. compare speeds. you will not get hundrads of mbits, but 50-80 without any trouble. no chance that openvpn limits you down to 5mbit.

Comment: If I do a download of a file on a 100 meg connection on the LAN I get around 12 MB/sec. If I do that same copy through the VPN I get around 4.5 MB/sec. My CPU is still getting spiked out on my OpenVPN server which has to be the bottleneck of the data push.

Comment: @n00b what protocol to encapsulate the traffic do you use - tcp or udp? try with udp, although - if you have stable link between vpn endpoints that should not matter too much. what cpu do you have on the host system for virtualization?

Comment: I am using udp for encapsulation. For the OpenVPN server, I am running it on an IBM xSeries 346 2x 2.8 GHz Xeon with 4 gigs of RAM. For the virtualization I am giving it 4 procs and 2 gigs of RAM with an umlimited cap and it's peaking out the entire server.

Comment: is the gigabit connection end-to-end ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using compression?

If so you would likely benefit from disabling `comp-lzo`.

Comment: Yes, we are currently using compression.

Comment: I turned off comp-lzo and this didn't help me at all.

Comment: No difference at all with it turned off at both ends? I'm surprised.

Comment: Unfortunately not....

Comment: LZO is a very fast and CPU friendly compression algorithm. if you where using LZMA or LZMA2 this would be a COMPLETELY different story